# Word,PDF Upload using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I would like to know, how to upload documents like word, pdf using Rails. Can I use paperclip for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Paperclip can be used for any file uploads

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout **AttachmentFu**, but Paperclip is the deFacto standard for this type of operation.